# Running scripts at build-time with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I was wondering what the recommended way is to run a script that generates some static XML files at build time. Ideally, those scripts should be ES Modules so code can be shared between those scripts and my Next / React application code.

I think I need to [customize the Webpack config](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) but I'm not sure how I can run code there that uses ES Modules (and not just uses require).

EDIT: I have something like this in mind, which should also work with Modules:

```js
{
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
  if (isServer) {
    require('./scripts/generate-xml');
  }

  return config;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could be more descriptive but from what I understand you need to run a particular script at Build-time for your NextJS app. You can make use of the getStaticProps() function provided by NextJS.

```js
// your NextJS page

function Mypage() {
  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}

// This is the function you need
export async function getStaticProps() {
// do anything you want to do at build-time
// A good way would be to call a function by importing and the function will be executed at runtime. 
}
```

You can see more detail at official docs - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#typescript-use-getstaticprops

On another note, If you want to generate XML for SEO reasons at Build time, a better way would be by using API routes and feeding that API route as your XML file location inside robot.txt. See this - https://github.com/toughyear/blog/blob/master/pages/api/posts-sitemap.js

Comment: I want to generate multiple XML files, so API routes would work. However, I only want to generate those files once, at build time. I updated the original answer to better explain what I have in mind.

Comment: Why do you say that using an API to create static assets is better? I think your above option is the best, as it would happen at compile time, and mean that you con't have to have node.js running to serve your sitemap and your rss feed no? What's the advantage to using an api route?

Answer (score 0):

if you use a custom babel.config.js, you can use [babel macros](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros), but this will opt out from SWC in Nextjs 12. I am searching for an alternative to be compatible with SWC. For now the only workaround is to have a "pre-build" script.

You can wrap your `npm run start` script to run anything you want before calling `next build`